# What is the purpose of git log's "reflog selector" format option?

Tags: git

Git log --format includes in its list of variables:

%gD: reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}

What does this do, and how can I make it work? It would be cool if it listed the reflogs my commits appeared in, but when I try it

```
git log --format="%h %gD"
```

... it's always blank. Only abbreviated hashes are listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a reflog information available to print you have to actual the `--walk-reflogs` or `-g` option. Otherwise you are just following commit ancestory and the reflogs are not used.